# Undefined child ID jeditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

jeditable settings

```
$('.editable').editable('includes/notes/save.php', {
    loadurl     : 'includes/notes/load.php?id=' + $(this).find("div").prop("id"),//undefined child ID
    type        : 'text',
    onblur      : 'submit',
    indicator   : '<img src="includes/notes/indicator.gif">',
    style       : 'display: inline'
});
```

html

```
<tr class="items">
    <td>
        <?php echo $data['item_name']; ?>
    </td>

    <td>
        <div class="editable inventory-notes">
            <!-- need to get the child id below into jeditable -->
            <div id="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">
                <div class="add_note"></div>
                <div class="edit_note"></div>
                <div class="delete_note"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>

</tr>
```

How can I get the ID `$data['id']` into jeditable `loadurl` ? I am using jQuery 1.6.2. The data set has around 1,200 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var id = $('.editable').find("div:first").attr("id");

$('.editable').editable('includes/notes/save.php', {
    loadurl     : 'includes/notes/load.php?id=' + id
    type        : 'text',
    onblur      : 'submit',
    indicator   : '<img src="includes/notes/indicator.gif">',
    style       : 'display: inline'
});
```

I see that second argument of `.editable()` is an `Object` and not a `Function`, so `this` will not work here. You've to store the `id` before and use it within `.editable()` configuration.

#### According to comment

I think your whole code is within `click()` handler and you need to use

```
var id = $(this).find('div:first').attr('id');
```

to get current clicked `id`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This works. However clicking on a new row brings up the previous `$data['id']`. Is there a way to prevent it from reusing the last clicked `id` ? Thank you thecodeparadox.

Comment: @Kyle it should bring the previous data, because id stored  it using `.editable().find..`

Comment: Thank you again thecodeparadox. I was afraid to edit the plugin because I'm not familiar with jquery plugins, it looks scary. I'm editing it now and applied your fix to the relevant location. All it working now. This is nice. =) `jquery is confusing` Thank you for your efforts thecodeparadox.